# Logstash - Set @timestamp to use microseconds

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

Is there a way to update @timestamp in logstash so that microseconds are added?

In Kibana we've set the format to 'Date Nanos', but in logstash when we're using the date filter plug in to set **@timestamp** with the timestamp from the file, the microseconds seem to be ignored.

I think this is because the date filter plugin handles millisecond level accuracy, is this right? If so, what is the best way to set @timestamp to show the microseconds from the file being ingested?

Thanks

**Sample from logstash file**

```
date {
    target => "@timestamp"
    match => ["file_timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"]
}
```

**Format in Kibana**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, logstash only supports millisecond precision. When elasticsearch started supporting nanosecond precision no corresponding changes were made to logstash. There are two open issues on github requesting that changes be made, [here](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/10822) and [here](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/11872).

The [Logstash::Timestamp](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/master/logstash-core/src/main/java/org/logstash/Timestamp.java) class only supports millisecond precision, because Joda, which it wraps, only supports milliseconds. Moving from Joda to native Java processing for time/date is mentioned in one of those issues. logstash expects [@timestamp] to be a Logstash::Timestamp (sprintf references assume this, for example)

You could use another field name, use a template to set the type to date_nanos in elasticsearch and process it as a string in logstash.

Comment: Hi, the limitation is specifically around the date filter plugin isn't it? Is there another way of modifying the timestamp field without using that?

Comment: Edited answer to address that. In short, "no".